# std::vector optimisation required

Tags: c++, std, c++builder

I've written a routine that uses `std::vector<double>` rather heavily. It runs rather slowly and AQTime seems to imply that I am constructing mountains of vectors but I'm not sure why I would be. For some context, my sample run iterates 10 times. Each iteration copies 3 c arrays of ~400 points into vectors and creates 3 new same sized vectors for output. Each output point might be the result of summing up to 20 points from 2 of the input vectors, which works out to a worst case of 10*400*3*2*20 = 480,000 dereferences. Incredibly the profiler indicates that some of the std:: methods are being called 46 MILLION times. I suspect I'm doing something wrong!

Some code:

```
vector<double>gdbChannel::GetVector() {
   if (fHaveDoubleData & (fLength > 0)) {
      double * pD = getDoublePointer();
      vector<double>v(pD, pD + fLength);

      return v;
   } else {
      throw(Exception("attempt to retrieve vector on empty line")); ;
   }
}

void gdbChannel::SaveVector(GX_HANDLE _hLine, const vector<double> & V) {
   if (hLine != _hLine) {
      GetLine(_hLine, V.size(), true);
   }
   GX_DOUBLE * pData = getDoublePointer();
   memcpy(pData, &V[0], V.size()*sizeof(V[0]));
   ReplaceData();
}

///This routine gets called 10 times
 bool SpecRatio::DoWork(GX_HANDLE_PTR pLine) {
   if (!(hKin.GetLine(*pLine, true) && hUin.GetLine(*pLine, true) && hTHin.GetLine(*pLine, true))) {
      return true;
   }
   vector<double>vK = hKin.GetVector();
   vector<double>vU = hUin.GetVector();
   vector<double>vTh = hTHin.GetVector();

   if ((vK.size() == 0) || (vU.size() == 0) || (vTh.size() == 0)) {
      return true;
   }
   ///TODO: confirm all vectors the same lenghth
   len = vK.size();
   vUK.clear();  // these 3 vectors are declared as private class members
   vUTh.clear();
   vThK.clear();
   vUK.reserve(len);
   vUTh.reserve(len);
   vThK.reserve(len);

   // TODO: ensure everything is same fidincr, fidstart and length

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (vK.at(i) < MinK) {
         vUK.push_back(rDUMMY);
         vUTh.push_back(rDUMMY);
         vThK.push_back(rDUMMY);
      } else {
         vUK.push_back(RatioPoint(vU, vK, i, UMin, KMin));
         vUTh.push_back(RatioPoint(vU, vTh, i, UMin, ThMin));
         vThK.push_back(RatioPoint(vTh, vK, i, ThMin, KMin));
      }

   }
   hUKout.setFidParams(hKin);
   hUKout.SaveVector(*pLine, vUK);
   hUTHout.setFidParams(hKin);
   hUTHout.SaveVector(*pLine, vUTh);
   hTHKout.setFidParams(hKin);
   hTHKout.SaveVector(*pLine, vThK);
   return TestError();
}

double SpecRatio::VValue(vector<double>V, int Index) {
   double result;
   if ((Index < 0) || (Index >= len)) {
      result = 0;

   } else {
      try {
         result = V.at(Index);
         if (OasisUtils::isDummy(result)) {
            result = 0;
         }
      }
      catch (out_of_range) {
         result = 0;
      }
   }
   return result;
}

double SpecRatio::RatioPoint(vector<double>Num, vector<double>Denom, int Index, double NumMin, double DenomMin) {
   double num = VValue(Num, Index);
   double denom = VValue(Denom, Index);
   int s = 0;
   // Search equalled 10 in this case
   while (((num < NumMin) || (denom < DenomMin)) && (s < Search)) {
      num += VValue(Num, Index - s) + VValue(Num, Index + s);
      denom += VValue(Denom, Index - s) + VValue(Denom, Index + s);
      s++;
   }
   if ((num < NumMin) || (denom < DenomMin)) {
      return rDUMMY;
   } else {
      return num / denom;
   }

}
```

The top AQTime offenders are:

> std::_Uninit_copy >, double *, std::allocator > 3.65 secs
>   and 115731 Hits
>
> std::_Construct 1.69 secs and 46450637 Hits
>
> std::_Vector_const_iterator >::operator
>   !=1.66 secs and 46566395 Hits and so on...

`std::allocator<double>::construct`,
 
`operator new`,
`std::_Vector_const_iterator<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator ++`, `std::_Vector_const_iterator<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator *`
`std::_Vector_const_iterator<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator ==`

each get called over 46 million times.

I'm obviously doing something wrong to cause all these objects to be created. Can anyone see my error(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are passing your function arguments by value.  Every time a `std::vector` is passed by value, a complete copy of the vector must be made.

Change these:

```
double SpecRatio::VValue(vector<double>V, int Index) {

double SpecRatio::RatioPoint(vector<double>Num, vector<double>Denom...
```

To:

```
double SpecRatio::VValue(const vector<double> &V, int Index)

double SpecRatio::RatioPoint(const vector<double> &Num, const vector<double> &Denom...
```

Because for your usage, you never actually needed separate copies of these vectors to be made.

Comment: You should also consider changing `gdbChannel::GetVector()` to pass the output vector to a reference parameter instead of returning the vector by value.  That can avoid another copy, especially if the compiler does not implement [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Answer (score 1):

You are inefficiently ("deep") copying your vectors in a few places due to the way you pass them and return them ("by value").  For example, your `VValue()` method is making a copy of its vector parameter, as is your `RatioPoint()` method, where both vector arguments are being (unnecessarily) copied in their entirety. Instead, you probably want to pass your vector arguments as a `const vector<double>&` (i.e, "by reference", like you do in `SaveVector()`).

Also, your GetVector() method may return a copy of the vector, although this will probably be avoided if the compiler optimizes it (as walrii pointed out in reply to my original erroneous post here).  If you are using C++-11, you can return a movable (as walrii also pointed out).  Failing these, the solution is a bit trickier -- you might consider allocating the vector on the heap and returning a shared or auto pointer to it.

Comment: Your second paragraph is a bit off.  NVRO will handle it and if you have c++11, so will move semantics.  Using a heap object will just slow it down due to the allocation.